# Ubuntu detects external HDD but doesn't mount it

Tags: mount, 14.10, external-hdd

When I connect my WD My Passport 1TB drive, it doesn't automatically mount. However, it *is* detected. I can see it using `sudo fdisk -l`, and even mount it manually using

`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/hooda/ext`

But having to mount it manually every time I connect is rather irritating. Why isn't Ubuntu automatically mounting it? All other HDDs/USB disks are being mounted. I'm using 14.10.

Edit:There's only a single partition

```
Partition FileSystem  Label     Size        Used        Unused      Flags
/dev/sdb1 ntfs        Hooda V2  931.48 GiB  808.70 GiB  122.78 GiB
```

There's nothing super-critical on it, but of course I wouldn't want to lose 800GB worth of data. The drive works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1) please connect the drive

2) open file manager on Ubuntu

3) do you see your drive on the side bar?

3a) **if yes** right click the drive and select mount

3b) **if no** close file manager, open terminal run **sudo fdisk -l** Reopen file manager, do you see your drive now?

Comment: the partitions on my system disk or the external disk?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: I have added the rest of details.

Comment: No, the software is not needed (it's for backup and stuff, but drive works without installing it). Further, I have another drive, WD My Passport 500Gb, and that mounts just fine on both Ubuntu and Windows.